# Using a Closure as a While Loop's Condition

Tags: swift, while-loop, closures

I want to use a closure as a condition for a while loop. This is what I have:

```
var x: Int = 0
var closure = {() -> Bool in return x > 10}
while closure {
    x += 1
    println(x) // never prints
}
```

It never prints anything. If I change it to `closure()`, it doesn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Your logic is backwards. You want to print while `x` is less than `10`, so:
2. when you call a closure directly you do so as you would a function, i.e. with parenthesis.

Updated code, tested with Swift 2.0:

```
var x: Int = 0
var closure = {() -> Bool in return x < 10}
while closure() {
    x += 1
    print(x)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems here.

Firstly, as written, your code won't even compile.  You need to change `while closure` to `while closure()`.

Second, the bigger problem, your `closure` logic is wrong.  `x > 10` never returns `true` because `x` is never greater than `10`.  Flip the sign over and it'll work.

#### Swift 2

```
var x = 0
var closure = { () -> Bool in return x < 10 }
while closure() {
    ++x
    print(x)
}
```

#### Swift 1.2

```
var x = 0
var closure = { () -> Bool in return x < 10 }
while closure() {
    ++x
    println(x)
}
```

Comment: Arguably, I might prefer this as `var closure = { val: Int -> Bool in return val < 10 }`, then... `while closure(x) { ... `

Comment: I would much prefer `for x in 0..<10`, but I suppose the OP is experimenting with closures and how they capture variables. =)

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the closure with `()`, and your condition is the wrong way around so that it's `false` at the beginning (it should be `x < 10`, not `x > 10`). Change to:

```
var x = 0
var closure: () -> Bool = { x < 10 }
while closure() {
    ++x
    print(x)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of abbreviation opportunities to make your code more concise and elegant.

```
var x = 0
let closure = { x < 10 }
while closure() {
  x++
}
x // 10
```